# How can I remove what I think is to be a virus?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, security, virus, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

I have used everything that I can think of. I'm not even sure how I even got this virus, if it is a virus. This is what it does:

I can't run any programs, this includes programs with any extension,
even `.bat` files. I can't do anything
in safe mode either. I can't run RKill, Internet Explorer, combofix,
roguefix, or anything else. I can't boot them off a CD using command prompt
even in safe mode. I have a Hirens boot CD (version 14.0) and that doesn't seem to help.
Here is a specific example of how it won't let me do anything.

I double click on "RKill" and I get a pop up window saying this:

> An unauthorized program is trying to run, please type in administrator password.

Then it says "Guest" in the user field and under guest I have to type the password. Here's the catch, guest is not admin nor does it have a password, there is only one password that I am aware of on this machine and it is the one I use to log in my admin account and that doesn't work. I am running Windows Vista Home Basic.

Comment: OW OW OW "As explained in the comments, this should remain a simple reference, and not a pretext to close any related question as duplicate of this one. Even if steps to follow are often the same, each situation is different. When referring to this question, suggest to the asker to update his question with more details about his situation: what worked, what didn't, what happened."

Answer (score 0):

First off, if it is malware that is designed to grab passwords, if you typed your password in then you'd best assume it is now with the bad guys so you'd best plan to change your passwords online and on your home PC.

Secondly, you should check out the question mentioned by @Nifle on **[what to do if your computer is infected.](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)**

I would always assume the worst, as an attacker could put whatever they want on your computer and hide it very well. Dust off and nuke from orbit!